# A better way to group actions of similar buttons?

Tags: vb.net

say I have a Button1 subroutine

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim buttonText As String = Button1.Text
        someOtherRoutine(buttonText)
    End Sub
```

I have a lot of such buttons in my main form. They all do the same thing like this. get the text and pass to some other routine. If i have 20 buttons, then i will have 20 such subroutines. Is there a better (or standard way) to do this without creating that many subroutines?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this one subroutine to handle *all* of the buttons:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
   Handles Button1.Click, _
   Handles Button2.Click, _
   ...
   Handles Button20.Click

      Dim myButton As Button = sender
      Dim buttonText As String = myButton.Text

      ...

End Sub
```

Comment: I thought you only had to put Handles once. Like Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click... You should point out to us send to get the buttons text like sender.Text.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko - answer updated before you submitted your comment ;)

Comment: hi, can you explain this subroutine? does it mean that I only need to click Button1 ? In my application, I need to click on Button2, Button3 and so on, not just Button1. thanks

Comment: @user216915 - The code registers the `.Click` event of all buttons with this event handler. Within, we are taking the `sender` parameter and casting it back to a button (which will be the button that was clicked) and using that reference to obtain the text on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28VS.80%29.aspx) to add the same event handler for every button or you can use a comma separated list in the [Handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y%28VS.80%29.aspx) clause.

```
Sub EventHandler() Handles Obj.Ev_Event, Obj2.Ev_Event
' Handle the event.
MsgBox("EventHandler caught event.")
EndSub
```